# jquery selector slow when 1000+ elements with 450Mhz machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got something like this which contains about 1000 dom elements

```
  <table id="tableId">
    <tr class="selected"><td>Text 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text 2</td></tr>
    ...
    <tr><td>Text 500</td></tr>
  </table>
```

problem is that i need to do something like this:

```
y = new selected tr;
$("#tableId").find("tr").removeClass("selected").eq(y).addClass("selected");
```

The problem here is the selector itself who takes about 600ms to process which is kinda too long for the things we are doing.

The machine im using uses a browser **opera10** and has only **450Mhz** running on linux!
Do you guys think that the problem comes from the machine being that slow?

Is there a way to improve the selector ?

Comment: You might consider having the server do this instead of the client. IE in particular is really horrible for table dom manipulations. Even checking an attribute can cause the entire table to dom refresh. If you make an ajax call to the server you can get a new table and insert it in one large chunk rather than messing with each individual row.

Comment: The problem we have is that the class is a background color. Making new requests is kinda too heavy for such a little thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll tell you how to do it via programming logic:

- store a reference to the "selected element"
- unselect it
- select the new one

by storing the currently selected element, you don't need to loop over tons and tons of tr elements to find the selected one.

maybe an easier option for you would be to give the currently selected option an id of "currentlySelectedTr. id lookups are really optimized by web browsers.

Comment: wow i just tried it (giving id to each tr and selecting with id) and it realy improves the performance by about 20 times with my benchmark. I'll try this in my real code tomorrow but i think this should be the answer thx :D

Comment: you dont need to give each element a unique id. just add/remove the id attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a good answer. You need to try a couple of things and compare benchmarks. Here are my two cents (again):

```
$("#tableId").children("tr").removeClass("selected").eq(400).addClass("selected");
```

Note that `.find` recursively travels down the nodes where as `.children` only looks at the elements immediately below the specified item. At least 50% less elements will be matched.

## [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/speed-selectors-999/7)

Comment: check this out http://jsperf.com/speed-selectors-999
my version is way faster but thx that you tried to help me

Comment: i actually never used .children its way faster thx for pointing me to this.

Comment: i updated version 8 from jsperf link to use id's to see the difference and it is HUGE with cached id's

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the script with:

```
$("#tableId tr").removeClass("selected").eq(y).addClass("selected");
```

Comment: @thecodeparadox. Sorry, I upvote when you're right and dowvote when you're not. :) This is how this site works.

Comment: Absolutely and you're 100% right. This will lead us to correct way. Thanks again friend.

Comment: @Marcio. My test shows they are the same. it should be faster if the browser support `querySelectorAll` function. and you can use it directly. anyway, if your machine is slow... there isn't much we can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the selector like this:

```
var myTableRow = $('#tableId').find('tr');
```

Then for toggling a class you could do this:

```
myTableRow.toggleClass('selected');
```

--EDIT--

I first created the cached selector like this:

```
var myTableRow = $('#tableId tr');
```

However, after reading [this 24 ways article](http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck) by Scott Kosman, I learned that the [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method is faster.

Comment: i tried to cache already before posting this post but it realy didn't make any significant difference.
difference was about 50ms won maybe at most.